# UIScrollView not showing up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

so basically I have an app that uses `-horizontalSelect` and it hides and unhides scrollViews once you select a cell inside the horizontalSelect. But the problem is that once you select "XBOX" everything disappears and nothing shows up, however once you click on PS3 the PS3 scrollView Appears.

Both scrollViews were added inside the storyboard.

Here's the code

```
-(void) horizontalSelect:(id)horizontalSelect didSelectCell:(KLHorizontalSelectCell*) cell {

    if([cell.label.text isEqualToString:(@"PS3")]) {
        self.ps3ScrollView.hidden = NO;
        self.xboxScrollView.hidden = YES;

        NSLog(@"PS3 SELECTED!");

    } else if([cell.label.text isEqualToString:(@"XBOX")]) {
        self.ps3ScrollView.hidden = YES;
        self.xboxScrollView.hidden = NO;
    NSLog(@"XBOX SELECTED!");
    }

   // NSLog(@"Selected Cell: %@", cell.label.text);
}
```

How it looks
PS3- http://gyazo.com/c7b6492e9703a750d67d4b4654d047c5

XBOX- http://gyazo.com/5f4ad67f17a104b53f7e37bd78eae98e

Comment: It s look like that you didn't added t xboxScrollView to the screen

Comment: Take a look at the storyboard, the scrollViews have been placed on the same spot http://gyazo.com/6348f8c4cbfba6466ec0df31f04e9788

Comment: Is the outlet hooked up properly to the xbox view? Could only be hooked up to the PS3 one so it hides and unhides it, but the XBOX view could be not connected so nothing shows

Comment: Silly me, I had the xboxScrollView inside the ps3ScrollView. I fixed it by adding the xboxscrollView back into the main view.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the `self.xboxScrollView` is underneath something. Try adding this line:

`[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.xboxScrollView];` (unless `self` is a view, then just remove `.view`)

directly after:

`self.xboxScrollView.hidden = NO;`

EDIT:
This is assuming you have the storyboard setup correctly and those print statements are working as intended.